# how to solve FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using **video_editor** package in flutter. When I at debug mode it works and no error but when I release the apk, the apps clash and show the error :

```
D/flutter-ffmpeg(10753): Getting media information for /data/user/0/com.example.apps/cache/file_picker/Screenrecorder-2021-05-19-15-53-57-515.mp4.
E/AndroidRuntime(10753): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
E/AndroidRuntime(10753): Process: com.example.apps, PID: 10753
E/AndroidRuntime(10753): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Bad JNI version returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.example.apps-QO20kuBv0uYvExYVArrO7A==/lib/arm64/libmobileffmpeg.so": 0
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1071)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.Config.<clinit>(Unknown Source:148)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.Config.nativeFFprobeExecute(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.f.a(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.f.b(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.f.a(Unknown Source:48)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at c.b.a.a.c.a(Unknown Source:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at c.b.a.a.c.doInBackground(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/AndroidRuntime(10753):        ... 3 more
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that all required dependencies are included within "dependencies:" in pubspec.yaml. Dependencies declared inside "dev_dependencies:" are not included in released app

Comment: thank you for your reply, all required dependencies are included within "dependencies". Inside dev_dependencies only has the default one

Answer (score 0):

Add the following entries into your **proguard-rules.pro** file. If you don't have this file you can create and put in app folder.

```
-keep class com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.Config {
    native <methods>;
    void log(long, int, byte[]);
    void statistics(long, int, float, float, long , int, double, double);
}

-keep class com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.AbiDetect {
    native <methods>;
}
```